# How to make auto-generated Text in UserForm Based on Table?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have created a Table1 that uses UserForm to add New row by pressing (Add New Record) Button, What I want in the UderForm once I select the Name from Combobox (comboName), the (txtDiscipline) will be auto-generated (appear automatically) based on the Table2 that specifies For each name a discipline.

[Table1 and Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9Uoj.png)

[The UserForm for adding Rows in Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4suqO.png)

**Update:**

[The Message after closing the userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3u93.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create 2 subs in userform and use find method when combobox change. notice that if You have the same names in column F this wouldnt work and then You need to define unique id for each item.

```
Private Sub comboName_Change()
Dim int_LR As Integer: int_LR = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row '   find last row of table
Dim str_Name As String: str_Name = Me.comboName                                 '   look up this name
Dim rng_FindRange As Range                                                      '   search range

Set rng_FindRange = ActiveSheet.Range("F3:G" & int_LR).find(str_Name)
If Not rng_FindRange Is Nothing Then
    Me.txtDiscipline = ActiveSheet.Cells(rng_FindRange.Row, 7)
Else    '   If Not rng_FindRange Is Nothing
    Me.txtDiscipline = "Name not found"
End If  '   If Not rng_FindRange Is Nothing

End Sub
```

and when userform initialize

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim int_LR As Integer: int_LR = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row '   find last row of table

Me.comboName.Style = fmStyleDropDownList '   combobox list style
For i = 3 To int_LR '   loop adding items to combobox
    Me.comboName.AddItem ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6)
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but when I close the UserForm as message occur and I dont know the exactly the reason for that msg. I upload a screenshoot of the msg above.

Comment: Try add code to userform_initialize event: me.showmodal=false and before end of comboname_Change event set rng_FindRange = nothing. u can also change event of comboname from change to keydown and bound makro to start after keyreturn down.